# undecidable sentences of first-order arithmetic whose truth values are unknown

Tags: lo.logic, co.combinatorics

Godel's undecidable sentences in first-order arithmetic were guaranteed to be true, by construction. But are there examples of specific sentences known to be undecidable in first-order arithmetic whose truth values *aren't* known? I'm thinking, by contrast, of the situation in set theory: CH is undecidable in ZFC, but its truth value is, in some sense, unknown.

Paris and Harrington [showed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paris-Harrington_theorem) the strengthened finite Ramsey theorem is true (in the sense of provable in second-order arithmetic) but undecidable in first-order arithmetic. I'm asking for "natural" examples in this general vein -- but whose truth values haven't yet been settled.

EDIT. Let me clarify my interest in the question, which is more philosophical than mathematical. I asked it on the basis of the following passage in Peter Koellner's [paper](http://logic.harvard.edu/koellner/QAU_reprint.pdf) "On the Question of Absolute Undecidability":

> The above statements of analysis [i.e. all projective sets of reals are Lebesgue measurable] and set theory [i.e. CH] differ from the early arithmetical instances of incompleteness in that their independence does *not* imply their truth. Moreover, it is not immediately clear whether they are settled at any level of the hierarchy. They are much more serious cases of independence.

What I'm asking is whether there *are* "much more serious cases" of independence even in first-order arithmetic -- and not in the trivial case of full-on ZFC, like V=L, etc. By a sentence with "unknown truth value," I just mean a sentence that hasn't been proved in a theory stronger than first-order arithmetic. (For example, Paris and Harrington proved the strengthened finite Ramsey theorem in second-order arithmetic.)

Comment: Harvey Friedman is working on combinatorial statements about (small) powers of bounded intervals of rational numbers (like Q[0,8]) which are equivalent to consistency of large cardinal axioms. Is this the sort of thing you were after?

Comment: I would be interested in something which is *not* of this sort. Anyway, all of Harvey's examples are true in the standard model. (Under appropriate background assumptions on large cardinals.)

Comment: I do not know about an specific sentence, but it is worth noticing that it is easy to build pair of sentences such that at one of them is of the kind you want. How? Let us consider $\psi$ an undecidable sentence which is true (e.g., $Con(ZFC)$) and let us consider $\varphi$ a sentence whose truth value is unknown (e.g., Riemann Hypthesis). Then, either the sentence $\psi \land \varphi$ or the sentence  $\psi \land \neg \varphi$ is of the kind you are interested on. 

Comment: I don't understand what you means by "true" or "truth value". Do you mean "provable in ZFC"?

Comment: Indeed, the main question I have is what "is not known" means. Is it "known" whether there is an inaccessible cardinal, or a measurable cardinal? What about V=L? 

Comment: I could swear I've essentially seen a question just like this before on MO but I can't find it. 

Comment: Edited question to address these concerns. V=L is too heavy-handed: I want an example in arithmetic (like Paris & Harrington give), not using the full resources of set theory.

Comment: @boumol: in what sense is Con(ZFC) true?

Comment: @Carl: I think the best scenario would be a arithmetic sentence $\phi$ such that both $PA+\phi$ and $PA+\lnot\phi$ are equiconsistent with $PA$, but for which we do not know whether $\phi$ or $\lnot\phi$ holds in ${\mathbb N}$. I doubt any "natural" such examples are known. 

Comment: I don't think you've addressed the issue of what "known" means. The standard model for first-order arithmetic is very tangible, so it's easy to argue that every first-order arithmetic sentence is either true or false. It's much harder to make this argument for set theory or even second-order arithmetic. That said, we don't actually know very much about the standard model, so there is an easy existence proof based on our perpetual ignorance.

Comment: Short of that, I suppose the next best scenario would be that ($\phi$ is "natural" and) $PA+\phi$ and $PA+\lnot\phi$ are provably consistent from appropriate large cardinal assumptions, but no such assumptions decide $\phi$ in ${\mathbb N}$. Again, I am not sure we know examples of any such $\phi$.

Comment: On the other hand, if statements such as the consistency of ZFC are not accepted as true in ${\mathbb N}$, then there are obvious and uninteresting answers to the question.

Comment: @François: the question is about first-order arithmetic anyway, so if you're hung up about my saying that the truth value of CH is unknown, it doesn't seem to me essential to the question -- and I asked for a specific example, not a mere "existence proof." Andres has a better sense of what I seem to want.

Comment: @symplectomorphic: You're reading up side down, the problem is that every arithmetical statement is either true or false in the standard model, so it's hard to come up with something which is 'unknown' like CH. I can't tell what you want from your question until you clarify what you mean by 'known'. If Andres has the right idea, then add that to your question.

Comment: François, perhaps this is what symplectomorphic means: Say that $X$ is *known at time $t$* if and only if someone has, at some time $t'\le t$, exhibited a proof of $X$ from ZFC + some standard large cardinal axiom.  Then he seeks an explicit example of arithmetical statement $X$ such that, taking $t$ to be the year 2011, $X$ is not known, but "PA does not prove $X$" is known and "PA does not prove $\neg X$" is known.  This seems roughly in line with Koellner's notion of absolute independence, and doesn't trivialize just because arithmetical statements are all either true or false.

Comment: It might also help symplectomorphic if someone explains why we run into silly examples if we draw a bright line at (say) ZFC specifically, or if we allow "unnatural" statements.

Comment: That would work, Tim, but I was secretly hoping for a non-transient notion (other than t=2011). Andres's next best scenario is close to that.

Comment: I don't believe your premise that "Godel's undecidable sentences in first-order arithmetic were guaranteed to be true, by construction."  Goedel's undecidable sentence is only true if the theory T in question is consistent.  So, for example, if we take T to be PA, then Goedel's undecidable sentence is true only if PA is consistent.  How do you know that PA is consistent?  Well we have a proof in ZF that PA is consistent; however ZF |- Con_PA only entails that PA is consistent if ZF is sound.  And how do we know that ZF is sound? ...

Comment: @symplectomorphic: I have said above to consider $Con(ZFC)$ as a proposal for a true statement because I believe it is true that ZFC is consistent. But, for sure, this claim is controversial (so I shouldn't have used this example). What only matters in the above argument is to consider a true statement (in case ZFC is inconsistent, then just consider the formula $\neg Con(ZFC)$ as the true statement in my above argument).

Comment: @boumol: I like your example, but unfortunately if ZFC is inconsistent, you cannot use $\neg Con(ZFC)$ in your construction because $\neg Con(ZFC)$ will be provable.

Comment: (symplectomorphic, for what it's worth, your sense of humor made me laugh out loud --- in a good way!)

Comment: An interesting but deeper question is that: should there be a Kreisel's sentence of which the truth value in the natural numbers (or in the so called the standard structure for the language of arithmetic) is unknown in the sense it's impossible to verify, know, then what would be the impact of such impossibility to the foundation of First Order Logic, specifically to the validity of Godel's Incompleteness and Completeness meta theorems? That is to say of course unless we can demonstrate beyond any doubt there's none of such Kreisel's sentences. It seems that the possible existence of such a Kr

Answer (score 22, accepted):

**Update.** I've improved the argument to use only the consistency of $T$. (2/7/12): I corrected some over-statements previously made about Robinson's Q.

---

I claim that for every statement $\varphi$, there is a variant way
to express it, $\psi$, which is equivalent to the original
statement $\varphi$, but which is formally independent of any
particular desired consistent theory $T$.

In particular, if $\varphi$ is your favorite natural open question,
whose truth value is unknown, then there is an equivalent
formulation of that question which exhibits formal independence in
the way you had requested. In this sense, *every* open question is
equivalent to an assertion with the property you have requested. I
take this to reveal certain difficult subtleties with your project.

**Theorem.** Suppose that $\varphi$ is any sentence and $T$ is any consistent theory containing weak arithmetic. Then there is another sentence $\psi$ such that

- $\text{PA}+\text{Con}(T)$ proves that $\varphi$ and $\psi$ are equivalent.
- $T$ does not prove $\psi$.
- $T$ does not prove $\neg\psi$.

Proof. Let $R$ be the Rosser sentence for $T$, the self-referential assertion that for any proof of $R$ in $T$, there is a smaller proof of $\neg R$. The [Gödel-Rosser theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rosser%27s_trick) establishes that if $T$ is consistent, then $T$ proves neither $R$ nor $\neg R$. Formalizing the first part of this argument shows that $\text{PA}+\text{Con}(T)$ proves that $R$ is not provable in $T$ and hence that $R$ is vacuously true. Formalizing the second part of this argument shows that $\text{Con}(T)$ implies $\text{Con}(T+R)$, and hence by the incompleteness theorem applied to $T+R$, we deduce that $T+R$ does not prove $\text{Con}(T)$. Thus, $T+R$ is a strictly intermediate theory between $T$ and $T+\text{Con}(T)$.

Now, let $\psi$ be the assertion $R\to (\text{Con}(T)\wedge \varphi)$. Since $\text{PA}+\text{Con}(T)$ proves $R$, it is easy to see by elementary logic that $\text{PA}+\text{Con}(T)$ proves that $\varphi$ and $\psi$ are equivalent.

The statement $\psi$, however, is not provable in $T$, since if it were, then $T+R$ would prove $\text{Con}(T)$, which it does not by our observations above.

Conversely, $\psi$ is not refutable in $T$, since
any such refutation would mean that $T$ proves that the hypothesis
of $\psi$ is true and the conclusion false; in particular, it
would require $T$ to prove the Rosser sentence $R$, which it does not by the Gödel-Rosser theorem. QED

Note that any instance of non-provability from $T$ will require the consistency of $T$, and so one cannot provide a solution to the problem without assuming the theory is consistent.

The observation of the theorem has arisen in some of the philosophical literature you may
have in mind, based on what you said in the question. For example, the claim of the theorem is mentioned in Haim Gaifman's new
paper "[*On ontology and realism in mathematics*](http://www.columbia.edu/~hg17/On%20Ontology%20and%20Realism%20in%20Mathematics-12-04-final.pdf)," which we read in my course last semester
on [the philosophy of set theory](http://boolesrings.org/hamkins/philosophy-of-set-theory-fall-2011/); see the discussion on page 24 of Gaifman's paper and specifically footnote 35, where he credits a fixed-point argument to Torkel Franzen, and an independent construction to Harvey Friedman.

---

My original argument (see edit history) used the sentence $\text{Con}(T)\to(\text{Con}^2(T)\wedge\varphi)$, where $\text{Con}^2(T)$ is the assertion $\text{Con}(T+\text{Con}(T))$, and worked under the assumption that $\text{Con}^2(T)$ is true, relying on the fact that $T+\text{Con}(T)$ is strictly between $T$ and this stronger theory. The current argument uses the essentially similarly idea that $T+R$ is strictly between $T$ and $T+\text{Con}(T)$, thereby reducing the consistency assumption.

Comment: There is nothing special about $\mathrm{Con}(T)$. If $\gamma$ is any sentence unprovable in $T$, and $\phi$ any sentence, then there is a $\psi$ such that $\vdash\gamma\to(\phi\leftrightarrow\psi)$, $T\nvdash\psi$, and $T\nvdash\neg\psi$. Proof: By the Gödel–Rosser theorem, there is an $\alpha$ independent of $T+\neg\gamma$. Put $\psi=(\gamma\land\phi)\lor(\neg\gamma\land\alpha)$.

Comment: Yes, I agree with that. 

Comment: The argument presumes that $T$ is computably axiomatizable, so that the Rosser sentence is available. This should be understood as a hypothesis in the theorem. (Vote up this comment if I should edit to say this explicitly.) 

Comment: The link to Gaifman's paper does not work.

Answer (score 3):

I think there is a little misunderstanding.

> Paris and Harrington showed the strengthened finite Ramsey theorem is true but unprovable in first-order arithmetic; I don't know if there's a proof that extends the result to full-on undecidability rather than just unprovability.

Indeed, the Wikipedia page is only talking about unprovability, but the negation of the strengthened finite Ramsey theorem is also unprovable in Peano arithmetic for "trivial" reasons: if you can prove this negation, then second order arithmetic can also prove this negation (because second order arithmetic is stronger than Peano arithmetic), so this would mean that second order arithmetic is inconsistent (because second order arithmetic proves the strengthened finite Ramsey theorem).

So if you take for granted that second order arithmetic is consistent, then your example is actually undecidable in Peano arithmetic. And there are other examples like [Goodstein's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goodstein_theorem).

Comment: Yes, I realize now that undecidability of the Ramsey theorem is trivial, once we have unprovability. But this is not an answer to the question: the Ramsey theorem -- like Goodenstein's theorem -- is, in fact, true on the standard model of arithmetic. I'm interested in undecidable cases where the truth value hasn't been settled.

Comment: Once again, I don't know what you mean by "truth value". An ultrafinitist (someone that does not believe in the infinity) will probably tell you that the truth value of Goodstein's theorem has not been settled at all, and that it's most likely false because experimentally you will never reach 0. On the other hand, someone like Woodin will probably tell you that the truth value of CH is known: it's false because there are strong arguments against it and few arguments for it. And most set theorists will tell you that large cardinal axioms are true because nobody want them to be false.

Comment: (of course this only applies to platonists, people who believe that there is a real mathematical universe somewhere, where every question has an answer)

Comment: Guillaume, these are not the sort of examples the question is after. If it is an issue, work in a metatheory extending ZFC with enough large cardinals.

Comment: @Andres, I know, I was just clarifying the unprovable/undecidable point.

Answer (score 3):

What you want is called [first-order] Arithmetical Splitting. I have spoken and written a lot about it in the last few years. Send me a message and I can show you some drafts about the current state of this most important topic.

Yes, we should not be able to form any preference, like in the case of PH, where it is clear that PH is better than \neg \PH.

Comment: Hi Andrey! I didn't ask the question, but naturally I am very interested in this topic. (Tried to email you but the email address I have for you has been discontinued.) Would you please email me some of those drafts you mentioned?



Answer (score 1):

I'd say Con(ZF) isn't known to be undecidable--it's only undecidable if it's true.  If it's false, that fact is $\Sigma^0_1$ and therefore provable.  We want a sentence that's $\Sigma^0_2$ or higher.

This might be an almost-example: http://www.cs.uchicago.edu/~simon/RES/collatz.pdf

It proves that a generalization of the 3n+1 conjecture is $\Pi_2$-complete.  But it's not quite what is asked, since it's about a family of problems rather than a single sentence.

Comment: Regarding the objection of your first paragraph, if Con(ZF) is false, then there are *no* independent sentences of any complexity.

Answer (score 0):

If you'll settle for an important open question that's independent from some weak fragments of PA, the P vs NP problem is an example.

http://www.scottaaronson.com/papers/pnp.pdf discusses this a little bit.

Or if you'll take a completely artificial problem that's more strongly independent, just generate a very long random proposition in PA's language, by rolling dice.  You won't know its truth value, and from Chaitin's theorem it will almost certainly be independent of any reasonable axiom system.

Comment: P = NP is independent of those weak fragments only if a certain cryptographic hypothesis holds, so this is not really an example.  I don't think the second example works either since symplectomorphic wants a *specific* example of a statement that is *known* to be undecidable.

Answer (score 0):

If we omit the qualification "natural" from the question, then, of
course, the most obvious examples are the arithmetized versions of
metamathematical sentences expressing the (absolute) consistency of
ZFC, or any axiom-system of set theory far weaker than ZFC within
which arithmetic can be developed. Indeed, e.g. Con(ZF) is a sentence
of arithmetic that we obtain by Godel-numbering from the
metamathematical sentence "there is no proof of 0=1 from ZF."  And if
ZF is consistent, then Con(ZF) is undecidable in Peano arithmetic with
unknown truth value. Actually, on the one hand, Con(ZF) implies
Con(PA), and the arithmetical proof of $\lnot$Con(ZF) would yield a
direct proof of the inconsistency of ZF.

As far as the "naturalness" condition is concerned, it seems that
there will be no easy way to find "natural" sentences of this
kind. Indeed, some natural candidates as e.g. the Goldbach conjecture
are excluded, since they should be true, if they turn out to be
undecidable. More precisely, any $\Pi_1$ sentence $S$ of arithmetic is true
whenever $S$ is undecidable. Indeed, if $S$ is false, then its negation is
a true $\Sigma_1$ sentence, and Peano arithmetic proves any true
$\Sigma_1$ sentence.